# Scope in exec callback

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am attempting to break out of a function based on an expression, however am having trouble with the scoping. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
function createService(dict, res) {
    // Ensure no duplicate
    var serviceExists = Service.find({name: dict['name']}).count().exec(function(err, doc) {
        return (doc !== 0);
    });

    console.log(serviceExists);

    if(serviceExists){
        res.send(500, "Duplicate document. Try updating existing entry or chooseing a different name");
        return;
    }

    //Insert the document
    service = new Service(dict);
    service.save(function(err) {
        if(!err) {
            res.send("Service saved");
        }
    });
}
```

The output of the console.log():

```
{ emitted: {},
  _events: { err: [Function], complete: [Function] } }
```

The end goal here is that the code will not reach the "Insert the document" portion if doc !== 0. Please let me know the correct way of doing this (Maybe using exceptions? That is the only idea I have left). Thanks

Comment: I got this result when looking for how to pass extra values to a call back. I found out how to do that and posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28120741/1695680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Service.find` is asynchronous. the callback in `exec` doesn't execute immediately. This causes problem 1. (If `Service....exec(...)` returned a value, your `console.log` would have already excuted, before the callback.)

Problem 2 is also pretty common. `return` in `exec()` doesn't return a value you can assign to a variable. (`exec()` does not return the return value of your anonymous function.)

Here is a fix for your code:

```
function createService(dict, res) {
    // Ensure no duplicate
    Service.findOne({name: dict['name']}).count().exec(function(err, doc) {
        var serviceExists = (doc !== 0);
        console.log(serviceExists);
        if(serviceExists){
            res.send(500, "Duplicate document. Try updating existing entry or chooseing a different name");
            return;
        }

        //Insert the document
        service = new Service(dict);
        service.save(function(err) {
            if(!err) {
                res.send("Service saved");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I also changed `find` to `findOne`, otherwise you'll get an array instead of a doc.

Comment: Perfect, thank you rdey. Don't know why it didn't occur to me that this was async.