# How can we access variable from callback function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

```
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'whoami';
var child = exec( cmd,
      function (error, stdout, stderr) 
      {
        var username=stdout.replace('\r\n','');
      }
);

var username = ?
```

How can I find username outside from exec function ?

Comment: You can have the username outside of the exec function (ie in global or child scope) or you can have an object keep track of some scope variables

Comment: Is exec method asynchronous?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass additional parameter to Javascript callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371673/pass-additional-parameter-to-javascript-callback-function)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can pass the exec function a callback. When the exec function determines the username, you invoke the callback with the username.

```
    var child = exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr, callback) {
        var username = stdout.replace('\r\n','');
        callback( username );
    });
```

Due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, you can't do something like this:

```
    var username;

    var child = exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr, callback) {
        username = stdout.replace('\r\n','');
    });

    child();

    console.log( username );
```

This is because the line `console.log( username );` won't wait until the function above finished.

Explanation of callbacks:

```
    var getUserName = function( callback ) {            
        // get the username somehow
        var username = "Foo";    
        callback( username );
    };

    var saveUserInDatabase = function( username ) {
        console.log("User: " + username + " is saved successfully.")
    };

    getUserName( saveUserInDatabase ); // User: Foo is saved successfully.
```

Comment: `    callback(username);
     ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at D:\wamp\www\keywords\ddd.js:7:5
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:630:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:730:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:943:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:451:12)`

Comment: You have to define a function to pass as a callback.

Comment: with you first 4 lined code I am getting "undefiend is not a function" at 3rd line "callback(username)"

Comment: How can we define a function "child" as per 2nd commnet?

Comment: For people new to this, the first code block is really confusing without the wrapper that passes the callback function. Also, it seems the callback from exec receives three strings: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Answer (score 4):

You can write the "exec" statement in a function that has a callback...
Like This

```
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'whoami';
function execChild(callback){
    var child = exec( cmd,
          function (error, stdout, stderr) 
          {
            username=stdout.replace('\r\n','');
             callback(username);
          }
 )};
    execChild(function(username){
    console.log(username);
});
```