# How to get variable from exec function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to use the value of the variable `w1` and `h1` outside the `exec` function, in `console.log`.

```
exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr) {

    var resolution = stdout.split("x");
    w1 = resolution[0];
    h1 = resolution[1];

});

console.log(w1 + " - " + h1);
```

The `console.log` displays the correct values ​​of the variables, but before displays this list of errors:

```
ReferenceError: w1 is not defined
at app.js:30:21
at callbacks (app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
at param (app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
at pass (app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
at Router._dispatch (app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
at Object.router (app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
at next (app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at Object.expressInit [as handle] (app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:30:5)
at next (app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at Object.query [as handle] (app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/query.js:44:5)
```

I found this similar question, but don't work for me.
[How can we access variable from callback function in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442829/how-can-we-access-variable-from-callback-function-in-node-js)

Thank you.

Comment: Just define them prior to the call.  `var h1, w1;` then call your `exec` call.

Comment: Or call the log function inside the exec so they will be in scope.

Comment: However, realize that exec is async so your console.log will run *before* the command completes.  You need to console.log inside the callback.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem based on your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues here:

**Issue 1** - because you haven't defined those variables outside of the function scope, they are available only within that scope. You need to first define them as variables outside of the scope - when you set them inside of the function, they will be available outside of the function.

**Issue 2** - you are trying to log the variables before they have been set. When you make a call to `exec`, you are passing a callback that will run asynchronously when the `exec` finishes. The script will then continue on to your `console.log` before the callback has been run. That means that no matter what, those variables will be undefined, unless you explicitly define them earlier. This renders issue 1 essentially moot.

Without knowing more about your intentions, I think this is what you should do:

```
exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr) {

    var resolution = stdout.split("x");
    w1 = resolution[0];
    h1 = resolution[1];
    console.log(w1 + '-' + h1);


});
```