# javascript (node.js) | using external params in a callback function's scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, callback, request

How can i pass the id variable into the api resquests callback function as the function only has three fixed arguments?

I mean i can't do this:

```
 var id = 6;
    request(url, function(err, resp, body, id) {
//using here the returned body and the id too..
}
```

and it won't let me add another argument, cause the real function is

`request(url, function(err, resp, body){}`

Regards,

Comment: you can explain better your question?

Comment: You don't have to pass it, it's defined in a higher scope and as such automatically available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call back is being invoked from the request module, you can just use the variable `id` as is inside the callback as it is defined in its outer scope, but the moment you do `function(err, resp, body, id)` it creates a new variable `id` inside the scope of anonymous callback and the id from the outer scope won't be accessible there.

```
var id = 6;
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
     //you can access id here as is.
}
```

Or if you really want to pass it you can do (It is of no use though):

```
var id = 6;
request(url, (function(id, err, resp, body) {
     //you can access id here as is.
}).bind(this, id);
```

Comment: The first example is an example of a closure (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). That's standard practice in JS. One thing to be careful of with it, however, is that if `id` changes before the callback function is executed then the `id` contain the new value not the original value.

Comment: I've also posted a similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28120741/1695680 I feel my example may be a little more obvious to understand.