# How to set value from call back function?

Tags: javascript

I am working with some existing javascript and I have the following code:

```
launchDialog(myUrl,function(result, returnValue){
   //whatever
});
```

This code launches a modal window and when that window closes, the callback function fires.

What I am wondering is if it is possible for me execute some javascript **from the modal** that will allow me to set the `returnValue` parameter of my callback function?

FYI:

Not sure if it matters, but this is a dumbed-down version of some existing SharePoint javascript.  I cannot change the functionality of the `lauchDialog` function, but I can add javascript to the modal and the callback function.

Comment: What do you mean "from the dialog"? A dialog can't execute javascript...

Comment: the `lauchDialog` function opens an aspx page in a modal window, so it can execute javascript.  Maybe dialog was a poor choice of words, I was just going off of what SharePoint is calling it in their function.

Comment: When you say modal window. Are you talking about a new browser window, a div in the same page or iframe maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
function tryMe (param1, param2) {
    alert(param1 + " and " + param2);
}

function callbackTester (callback) {
    callback (arguments[1], arguments[2]);
}

callbackTester (tryMe, "hello", "goodbye");
```

Theres an example, i think thats what your trying to do.

Used the follow source for example: [JavaScript: Passing parameters to a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function)

Comment: Hrrm this is close, but in my example I don't have access to the `callbackTester` function.  In my example `callbackTester` would open a modal window, where I could execute some javascript.  `callbackTester` would be the equivalent of my `launchDialog` method.

Comment: hmm ill seee what i can come up with

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could store the `returnValue` in an external variable that is shared with the modal.

```
var myApp = {}; // your namespace
myApp.returnValue = 'something'; // you can override this wherever

launchDialog(myUrl, function(result, returnValue){
   returnValue = myApp.returnValue;
});
```

Comment: So would the external variable be available to javascript that runs from the modal window that opens?

Comment: I don't know, depends on your environment, but shouldn't be hard to test. In any case you can always store your app config in a separate file `app_config.js` that you load whenever you need it.

Comment: Keep in mind I haven't tested this myself. I'm just thinking this might work but maybe it's more complicated than it seems...

Comment: Unfortunately I doesn't look like I have access to `myApp.returnValue` from my modal window.  Any suggestions for getting around that?