# JSON data and functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

So I am having troubles understanding passing JSON data.

```
function getFooterContent(){
//ajax call to get json file 
$.getJSON("scripts/pageData/footer/footerData.json", function(jsonData){
    console.log(jsonData);
    return jsonData;
}).fail(function(){
    console.log("fail");    
    return -1;
});

//Return the json file 
}

function someFunction(){
    var someContent = new Object();
someContent = getFooterContent();
console.log(someContent);
}
```

So right now I'm calling a JSON file. And when I console.log(jsonData) I get an Object, which is what I want. So then I can someContent.theContent. Though when the jsonData is returned to the someFunction and I console.log(someContent) I get undefined. I don't understand, I thought it would be an object like it is in the getJSON function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is beacause `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. So, when `getFooterContent()` returns, at that point the JSON data hasn't been retrieved yet, hence the `undefined`.

What you should instead do is have `getFooterContent()` return a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) object.

```
function getFooterContent() {
    var promise = $.getJSON("url");
    return promise;
}

function someFunction() {
    var promise = getFooterContent();
    var outsideCopy;

    promise
    .done(function(data) {
        outsideCopy = data;
        console.log(outsideCopy);
    })
    .fail(function(e) {
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

The above example can be shortened by removing the variable declarations. I left them in so the code is easier to understand

Comment: But then how do I access the data that the promise has?

Comment: The data is the first parameter passed into the `done` function. See the `console.log(data);` statement.

Comment: So do I have to keep the data inside that function? There's no way for me to use the data outside the function?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how you can assign it to a variable outside that function

Comment: Though if I place the outsideCopy outside of the promise I get undefined? Again I know it isn't synchronized. Do I pass outsideCopy to a function then?

Comment: Yes, pass it to a function from within done(). Everything has to be event based.

Comment: Okay, great. I get it. Thank you both.

Answer (score 4):

getJSON is called asynchronously, so you are not getting what you expect.

Let me explain:

```
function getFooterContent(){
//ajax call to get json file 
$.getJSON("scripts/pageData/footer/footerData.json", 
  function(jsonData){ // This function is executed when request is ready and server responds with OK
    console.log(jsonData);
    return jsonData;
}).

fail(function(){ // This when servers responds with error
    console.log("fail");    
    return -1;
});

//Return the json file 
// You are returning undefined actually
}

function someFunction(){
    var someContent = new Object();
someContent = getFooterContent();
console.log(someContent);
}
```

You need:

```
function someFunction(){
    var someContent = new Object();
    getFooterContent(function(someContent){
      // someContent is passed by getFooterContent
      console.log(someContent);

    });
}
```

Here is how you pass arguments to a callback [JavaScript: Passing parameters to a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function)

For your function it will be:

```
function getFooterContent(done, fail){
  $.getJSON("scripts/pageData/footer/footerData.json", 
  function(jsonData){ // This function is executed when request is ready and server responds with OK
    // console.log(jsonData);
    // return jsonData;
    done.call(null, jsonData); // or done.apply()
}).

fail(function(){ // This when servers responds with error
    // console.log("fail");    
    // return -1;
    fail.call(); // or fail.apply()

});
}
```

Comment: So if I want to save the jsonData to a variable and return it, how would I do so?

Comment: Alright one last question hopefully. The function(jsonData) is the callback function I am executing, correct? And by your example, the getFooterContent execution sends a function with a parameter with someContent. How does this get returned to the someFunction?

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. I just don't understand the last bit. I am able to print the someContent now. Though when I have someContent = getFooterContent(); and the function is as function getFooterContent(done, fail) like you have. Though I don't understand what done and fail are nor the done.call(null, jsonData);

Comment: Though it doesn't work when I removed the promise code below.

Comment: `Though I don't understand what done and fail are` this is passing functions in  parameters list of other functions.

Comment: `nor the done.call(null, jsonData);` I got complicated there you can use `done(jsonData)`

Comment: So, is done a function I define? Or are you talking about the .done in jQuery's callback function? I'm still having a hard time conceptualizing where the data from the .getJSON() method. I understand it is an asynchronous call and that data is not synchronized with my current Javascript and I guess I'm trying to get it synchronized. Though I got it working when I did with the promise example below. Would I just do the .done and call the Javascript function I want and send the data with it? Then store it into a variable in that function?