# Adding extra args to a request callback.

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

The request function (from this [library](https://github.com/mikeal/request)). Has the following defines:

```
request(url, callback)
```

The callback argument gets 3 arguments:

- An error when applicable (usually from http.ClientRequest object)
- An http.IncomingMessage object
- The third is the response body (String or Buffer, or JSON object if the json option is supplied)

So I have a function called handle response like so:

```
function handleRespone(error,incomingmessage,responsebody)
```

I'm calling it like so:

```
  request(url, handleRespone)
```

I want to add an extra parameter to the handleResponse but I'm not sure how that works. I tried it adding it `request(url, handleRespone(extra))` but when I do a `console.log(extra)` in the handleRespone function it doesn't have the value. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just define the var outside the scope of `handleResponse`, it will work

```
var extra = "panda";

function handleResponse(error, incomingmessage, responsebody) {
  console.log(extra); // "panda"
}

request(url, handleResponse);
```

Or, you could use an anonymous function wrapper and pass as many args as you want to your handleResponse function

```
request(url, function(err, incomingmessage, responsebody) {
  handleResponse(err, incomingmessage, responsebody, extra, foo, bar);
});
```

Otherwise, It's a little hacky (as it requires you to prepend the "extra" parameters to the beginning of your function), but you could use `Function.prototype.bind`

```
function handleResponse(extra, error, incomingmessage, responsebody) {
  console.log(extra); // "panda"
}

request(url, handleResponse.bind(null, "panda"));
```

Comment: The `bind` solution is not hacky at all; it just requires modern browsers.

Comment: I only mention it as hacky because it forces him to put the `extra` variable at the beginning of the function parameters. I don't think this is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to catch your variable with the *arguments* object.

In your case, try

```
     function handleRespone(error,incomingmessage,responsebody){
             console.log(arguments[3]); 
             // your stuff ..
     }
```

I hope it helps you. [Some information on *arguments*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Comment: the `request` function is not written with his extra variable in mind, and it's only going to pass 3 arguments.