# Pass a paramerter to call back function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to nodejs and i need to know how to pass the parameter to callback function.

```
function scheduler(key, cron, callback){

  //cron-job-manager
  manager.add('key', '* 30 * * * *', callback)
}

function callback(key,cron){
 console.log(cron);
}

schdeduler("key", " * * * * *", callback);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function

Comment: Still i dont under stand the solution . can you please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a closure for your `callback`. You need to move `callback` function inside `scheduler`:

```
function scheduler(key, cron, callback){

  function callback() {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(cron);
  }

  //cron-job-manager
  manager.add(key, cron, callback)
}

schdeduler("key", " * * * * *", callback);
```

---

OR use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function scheduler(key, cron, callback){

  //cron-job-manager
  manager.add(key, cron, callback.bind(this, key, cron))
}

function callback(key, cron) {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(cron);
}

schdeduler("key", " * * * * *", callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

as per the comment in your cese it would be:

```
function callback(key, cron) {
    console.log(key + ", " + cron);
}

function scheduler(key, cron, callback) {
    //manager.add('key', '* 30 * * * *', callback);
    callback();
}

scheduler("key", " * * * * *", function() {
    callback("key", " * * * * *");
});
```