# how to pass a function requiring parameters as another's function arguments?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this function,

```
function foo (foo1, foo2) {
   ...
}
```

I need to pass it as an argument of another function :

```
caller(foo);
```

how is the most proper way to pass the arguments of **foo** in the `caller` function ?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
function internalMethod(a, b) {
   console.log(a);
   console.log(b);
}

function externalMethod (method) {
    method (arguments[1], arguments[2]);
}

externalMethod (internalMethod, "First argument", "Second argument");
```

Hope it help.