# How to pass parameters / arguments from one javascript snippet to another, when evaluated

Tags: javascript, wsh

My goal is to execute a javascript snippet using another javascript snippet using

`new Function(x1, x2, x3, functionBody)` call.

My problem appears when i need to pass parameters to the function, this is because functionBody may appear as a new Js script with global declarations and calls.

```
function main() {
var a = x1;
var b = x2;
var c = x3;
....
....
}

main(); // this is the function that starts the flow of the secondary Js snippets
```

**Edit:** I have a script responsible for downloading and executing another Js script. each downloaded script is executed by a global call to main(), which is unknown to the caller script.

Comment: You're suggesting a completely unconventional solution to a problem you haven't even described to us. All I'm hearing is "these wires don't connect" but you somehow failed to tell everyone that we're trying to defuse a bomb.

Comment: Zoom out. What is the actual goal?

Comment: @naomik: i have edited the post, thanks!

Comment: I don't know I got the sense of the question, but to me it looks like that your are looking for a way to pass parameters to callback. I think this questions and answers might give you a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function

Comment: @jjczopek, In the link you provided me with, they used the 'Arguments' known variable, however, in my example, the secondary script, starts from the global namespace, which from my tests, didn't recognize the 'Arguments' variable

Comment: I do not understand why the `wsh` tag has been used here. Is this a JScript classic question? If true then the `jscript` tag should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding how the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor works.

```
// This does not create a function with x1, x2, x3 parameters
new Function(x1, x2, x3, functionBody)

// This does 
new Function('x1', 'x2', 'x3', functionBody)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Specifying_arguments_with_the_Function_constructor

```
// Create a function that takes two arguments and returns the sum of those arguments
var adder = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');

// Call the function
adder(2, 6);
// > 8
```