# WSH (JScript) pass CLI arguments to another script that is activated internally

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, jscript, wsh

So I have my `JScript` script `s1.js`

```
var objArgs = WScript.Arguments;
WScript.Echo(objArgs.length)
```

when `s1.js` is run using [WSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)
I get the expected`WScript.Arguments`.

It gets tricky however when I run `s1.js` internally. Say I have another script `s2.js`:

```
var F = new Function(strScript); // strScript is the content of s1.js
(F)("test");
```

When running `s2.js`, with whatever CLI argument, `var objArgs = WScript.Arguments` defined in `s1.js` get the same arguments I passed to `s2.js`.

This does not surprise me since I assume `var objArgs = WScript.Arguments` is global and set by `WSH`.

### Question

1. How do I activate `s1.js` (internally in `s2.js`) and pass CLI params to it?
2. How do `s1.js` can distinguish between the two different ways of running it and read its arguments properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about WScript, but it seems like it's a global member among all Js snippets. I've done some basic tests and in-fact, WScript.Arguments is identical among all instances. The root for your problems lays within the new Function() call, As the first N-1 parameters declare the template for parameters, and the last one function's body.

Here's the answer that helped me -> [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32050442/1025124)