# Passing additional parameters to callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using mssql in node.js executing an SP:

```
var fnGetMapping = function(results) {

        new sql.Request(db.sqlConnection)
            .input('myParam', sql.VarChar(60), 'myValue')
            .execute('usp_MySP', fnProcessUUIDData);
};
```

Now my fnProcessUUIDData looks like this:

```
var fnProcessUUIDData = function(err, recordsets) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error calling MS SQL: " + err.message);
    } else {
        if (recordsets[0].length > 0) {

        } else {

        };
    }
};
```

What I need now is to pass one of my own parameter into fnProcessUUIDData.

I read some [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function) that this is possible but I couldn't get it working on my case, would appreciate some comments if what I want to do is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass some extra arguments without loosing the context.

```
new sql.Request(db.sqlConnection)
  .input('myParam', sql.VarChar(60), 'myValue')
  .execute('usp_MySP', function(...args) {
    fnProcessUUIDData.apply(this, args.concat(some, extra, parameters));
  });

var fnProcessUUIDData = function(err, recordsets, some, extra, parameters) {
  console.log(this, some, extra, parameters);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply` overcomplicates things because `fnProcessUUIDData` is a plain old function and not a method (it doesn't use `this` internally). All you need to do is wrap it in another function:

```
new sql.Request(db.sqlConnection)
  .input('myParam', sql.VarChar(60), 'myValue')
  .execute('usp_MySP', function(err, recordsets) {
    fnProcessUUIDData(err, recordsets, additional_parameter);
  });
```