# Passing a function as an argument

Tags: javascript, function, geolocation

I am teaching myself javascript and one of the exercises I have tried makes no sense to me.

In the code below 'position' is a parameter that must be defined. However, when I pass the function, `displayLocation` as an argument to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, the code executes flawlessly, despite no argument being passed. When I try `coords.longitude` in the console without the `position` argument, it does not work.

How does the code work without a defined argument?

```
function displayLocation(position)
{
  var latitude = latitude.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  var div = document.getElementById("location");
  div.innerHTML = latitude + " " + longitude;
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
```

Comment: Please give an example of the output both for the working and non working version.

Comment: Here is a link to the working code that was recommended by my text book. https://jsfiddle.net/2o4eLckf/1/#&togetherjs=CMK3uEvhVa

Comment: Not to be picky, but the first line in this function should probably read `var latitude = position.coords.latitude;`.

Comment: Here is the non-working version: https://jsfiddle.net/rq74mhpj/#&togetherjs=dVAE8GIAPv. I cannot understand how an undefined argument makes such a difference to the code.

Comment: Usually the [API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) will tell you what parameters are passed into the callback(s)

Answer (score 0):

> When I try coords.longitude in the console without the position
> argument, it does not work...
>
> How does the code work without a defined argument?

Arguments of function in JavaScript are optional.
If you don't pass it, it has as value : `undefined`.
So, yes the function accepts an invocation with a missing argument  `position` but `position.coords` would not be usable.

Comment: So it is calling `undefined.coords.longitude`?

Comment: Indeed and you should have a message error in your JS console that said that you cannot read property `coords` of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);` calls your function with an instance of [`Position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Position), as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition).

Please take into account that `displayLocation` is not called immediately but delayed. This is why you pass it as a *callback* function.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing when you do

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
```

is that you are calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, and giving it a handle to your function `displayLocation`.  You cannot say that `displayLocation` is getting called without an argument.  That depends on what `getCurrentPosition` does with that handle.  What it does is that it creates a **position** object, and then calls the function you gave it, with that object as a parameter.  More succinctly, `getCurrentPosition` calls `displayLocation` with a position object, it created, as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at [Geolocation.getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition). The required parameter `success` is a *callback function*.

Inner workings of the `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation)` will look roughly like the following:

```
function getCurrentPosition(callback, ...){

  var positionGCP;
  ...
  ...

  positionGCP = *someposition*;
  // done getting current position

  callback(positionGCP) 
  //passed in function gets called back!
}
```

and the last line (`callback(positionGCP)`) really runs `displayLocation(positionGCP)` since `callback == displayLocation`.

Does that make sense?

The following link may help:
[Passing parameters to a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function)