# Passing parameters to a callback function using arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I know this is a [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3458553/1374554) question with ES5, but I am looking for the syntax with ES6 arrow function. My code below:

```
fetchItems = (callback) => {
    //After ajax success
    callback(response);
}

const myParams = {name:"John"}
this.fetchItems((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

For the above scenario, I want to pass some parameters(`myParams`) along with the function call, how can I achieve that?

Comment: What is `getCountries` what is `this.fetchItems` and how should they be related?!

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: As there is no difference between arrow and regular functions in that regard, I'm voting to close this.

Comment: @JonasW. I guess the question is about "some parameters", since `arguments` does not work in lambda functions

Comment: @Jonas W Now I realized that but some scenario it was not worked for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that:

```
const fetchItems = (callback, ...params) => {
    //Do whatever you want with the params
    callback(response);
}
```

Example of usage:

```js
const fetchItems = (callback, ...params) => {
    callback(params);
}
    
fetchItems (console.log, 'foo', 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

More of less you can do it the same way

```
const getCountries = (data, callback) => {
    //After ajax success
    callback(response);
}

getCountries("data", ()=>{});
```