# JavaScript Callback Inner Function not Executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, callback

I have a client-side web-application that takes a csv-file, parses it into various data types, searches for something specific, and displays a table with the answer on the screen. The search function returning a null string. This occurs because its search parameter, returned by a callback function and put into lib, returns null.

I'm fairly certain this is a callback issue, but I've messed around with the order so much I'm not sure what goes where anymore in my html...A second set of eyes would be appreciated.

**The desired series of events**

1. fileToArray() gives us an array
2. search() looks in the array for its specified item and returns a csv-format string containing what it found
3. displayTable takes that csv-format string and outputs it to the desired location

**The Code**

```js
// jQuery call to fetch the client-side csv file - this works when called by itself.
const fileToArray = () => {
    console.log("fileToArray started.");
    $.get({
        url: CSV_LOCATION,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("splitting result by newline...");
            let csvLines = result.split("\n");
            console.log("split successful. generating array into retval ...");
            let retval = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < csvLines.length; i++) {
                // [0][0] is number [0][1] is class, [0][2] is unit, [0][3] is lesson
                retval[i] = csvLines[i].split(",");
            }
            console.log("success! Returning retval.");
            return retval;

            // callback(result);
            // return result;
        },
        failure: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("ERROR: fileToString(): " + xhr + " ||| " + status + " ||| " + error);
            alert("ERROR: fileToString(): " + xhr + " ||| " + status + " ||| " + error);
        }
    })
};

// PRECONDITION: form is #search-params in index.js
//      > lib is the result of fileToArray()
// POSTCONDITION: result is a csv-format string to be passed to displayTable() in index.js
const search = (form, callback) => {
    console.log("search called...");
    // vvvvv The probable root of the problem vvvvv //
    let lib = callback;

    console.log(lib.length + " is lib's length.");

    let result = "";
    console.log("search nested for loop called...");
    for (let i = 0; i < lib.length; i++) {
        // check class
        console.log("checking class " + form.class.value + "...");
        if (lib[i][1] === form.class.value) {
            // check unit
            console.log("checking unit " + form.unit.value + "...");
            if (Number(lib[i][2]) === Number(form.unit.value)) {
                console.log("adding to result...");
                result += lib[i] + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("search success! result: " + result.length + " characters");
    console.log(result);
    return result;
};
```

```html
<!-- I'm almost 100% certain I've messed up the callback in this button,
but I still don't quite understand how... I've played with
displayTable(fileToArray(search(...))), but I don't quite know how it should go -->
<button class="btn btn-primary"
                onclick="displayTable(search(document.getElementById('search-params'), fileToArray), $('#card-display'))">
            Submit
</button>
```

**What I've tried**

I have looked to the following sites for inspiration (none have helped):

1. [JavaScript is Sexy](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)
2. [JavaScript: Passing parameters to a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function)
3. [JavaScript Callback Functions](https://www.dashingd3js.com/lessons/javascript-callback-functions)
4. [Passing arguments to callback functions](https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/passing-arguments-to-callback-functions/)

**In Summary**

It's painfully obvious I still don't understand callbacks fully. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the js function `displayTable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `async` / `await`

```
const displayTable = async () => {
    let arrayFromFile = await fileToArray(); // fileToArray executes and assigns the returned value when it completes
    let searchedData = search(form, arrayFromFile);
    // Display the table
};
```

Comment: Only if `fileToArray` was changed to actually return a promise for the expected vale

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @kapantzak for the inspiration!! Turns out, I was using callbacks horribly bass-ackwards. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), the old-school async style is something akin to

```
doSomething(function(result) {
  doSomethingElse(result, function(newResult) {
    doThirdThing(newResult, function(finalResult) {
      console.log('Got the final result: ' + finalResult);
    }, failureCallback);
  }, failureCallback);
}, failureCallback);
```

So, the relevant code now looks like this:

```js
const fileToArray = (callback) => {
    // console.log("fileToArray started.");
    $.get({
        url: CSV_LOCATION,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (result) {
            let csvLines = result.split("\n");
            let retVal = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < csvLines.length; i++) {
                // [0][0] is number [0][1] is class, [0][2] is unit, [0][3] is lesson
                retVal[i] = csvLines[i].split(",");
            }
            callback(retVal);
        },
        failure: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("ERROR: fileToString(): " + xhr + " ||| " + status + " ||| " + error);
            alert("ERROR: fileToString(): " + xhr + " ||| " + status + " ||| " + error);
        }
    })
};
// =======

const search = (form, lib, callback) => {
    let result = "";
    let formClass = form.class.value.toLowerCase();
    let formUnit  = form.unit.value.toLowerCase();
    let formLesson = form.lesson.value.toLowerCase();
    for (let i = 0; i < lib.length; i++) {
        // check class
        if (lib[i][1].toLowerCase() === formClass) {
            // check unit
            if (Number(lib[i][2].toLowerCase()) === Number(formUnit)) {
                result += lib[i] + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
    callback(result);
};
```

```html
        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                onclick="fileToArray(function(result) {
                  search(document.getElementById('search-params'), result, function(newResult) {
                    displayTable(newResult, $('#card-display'));
                  });
                });">
            Submit
        </button>
```

This righted the wrongs and caused my search and display to function properly.