# Javascript: How to pass a callback with intended argument

Tags: javascript

**I want to print a string of my choice to the console after 2 seconds.**

This prints `'Hello'` to the console after 2 seconds:

```
function log() {
  console.log("Hello")
}

t = setTimeout(log, 2000)
```

But I didn't get to choose which string gets printed. It was hardcoded in the function.

This next bit of code does print `'myChoice'` to the console but it does it immediately, rather than waiting 2 seconds:

```
function log(st) {
  console.log(st)
}

t = setTimeout(log("myChoice"),2000)
```

That's because, as I understand, setTimeout wants me to feed it a function.

**How do I feed the `log` function to setTimeout and also tell it that when it runs it I want it to use whatever string I give it?**

*Notes*

- I'm not actually concerned with logging things after 2 seconds. This is a prototype question for my more general question of how to tell javascript which parameters I want a function to use when it's called.
- Bonus question: How could I have phrased my question title better? Is "callback" even the right word here?

Edit: 
Some people marked this as a duplicate, and indeed the question title is pretty much the same as [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function). But, the other question's body seems to have anchored all the answers to a particular way of solving the problem, ie using an intermediate function.
I think that the answer I got here is the best one given the question title.

Comment: hint : `log("myChoice")` is not a function. It's the return value of the function log after having been executed.

log is a function, but it needs a parameter. hence, a good solution to have a function that doesn't need a parameter, but calls log twith the right parameter, is Clarity's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setTimeout` accepts a function as an argument:

```
setTimeout(() => log("myChoice"), 2000)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Actually I've seen and used that `() => stuff` notation quite a lot without truly understanding. Any reference to what it's called or a complete explanation?

Comment: You mean the arrow function? Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Workarounds

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a fabric function?

```js
function log(str) {
  console.log(str)
}

// As fn - function, next arguments
// Any amount of args
function pass_args(fn, ...args) {
  return () => {
    fn(...args)
  }
}

t = setTimeout(pass_args(log, "My arg"),2000)
```