# JavaScript Pass Parameter to Callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, asynccallback

I'm working with a JavaScript library, and it takes callbacks as a parameter to functions, that execute when the function is completed. So, for instance, I have something like:

```js
bot.dig(target, callBackFunc)
```

and `callbackFunc` is something like:

```js
function callBackFunc(err) {
   console.log("hi");
   return 0;
}
```

and this is fine.

However, I would like to be able to actually pass parameters into this callBackFunc, something like:

```js
bot.dig(target, callBackFunc("hello!"))

function callBackFunc(err, input) {
   console.log(input);
   return 0;
}
```

but this does not work/throws a bunch of errors. How can I accomplish passing a parameter into this callback function?

Thank you!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3458816/5648954), you can use `.dig(target, function(err) {callbackFunc(err, "Hello")})`

Comment: ah awesome thank you so much!